# Schedule triggered flow not running for all Resources

Tags: visual-workflow, customsetting, schedulebatch, scheduled, schedule

I have a schedule triggered flow that runs weekly on the Resource object.
I have a custom setting checkbox which I use to denote whether the flow should run that week or not(bi-weekly pay schedule).
The custom setting is for the System Administrator profile.
The flow starts by checking this custom setting and if the checkbox is marked true, the flow runs and a record is created.
When the flow runs on schedule only one record is created for me (creator of the flow).  Any idea to why my flow is not creating records for any other Resources?

A resource is a user in our internal org

Comment: you'll need to use [edit] and show the relevant elements of the Flow

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this to troubleshoot. Save your flow as a new flow (not a new version), in the screen dialogue pick autolaunched flow. Create a resource called recordId and mark it as an input variable. Use this variable to get the record and make necessary adjustments to have your flow run without issues. Copy a recordId from within Salesforce, debug your flow, paste this record id as input in your debug start dialogue. See what your debug says. Do this on several records.